Can 間 (あいだ) be used with plain form of verbs?
This question is heavily related to mine, which will add some details and try to present things from my own perspective.
In my grammar book, 間 is introduced to express simultaneity. In the case of nouns, one would just use Nの間, meaning "during N". On the other hand, in the case of verbs, my books says to use (I will only write the subordinate clause from now on)
Sentence 1 (plain form)間. Since we're expressing a duration, in most cases, and in all examples of my book, it is not just the plain (aka dictionary) form of the verb, but the plain form of its ~ている form. I understand that in most cases that's what happens, but the way my book presents it, it seems that in some cases it is admissible to use directly the plain form of the verb, such as replacing

田中さんが食べている間+[main clause]

with

田中さんが食べる間+[main clause]

with probably a different nuance. Most sources I've read, unlike my book, only mention ~ている間, but I have good reasons to think that my book is not wrong, due to this additional remark (for which I'd be grateful if you made a comment about):

If there is a copula です/だ in the subordinate clause before 間, it is replaced by の

This is similar to だ+のです-->なのです and it seems to precise a remark to be just vagueness.
Posting the book is no use, as it is an Italian translation, but for reference it is the grammar section of lecture 11 of translation of ICU's Japanese for College Students: Basic (first lecture of second volume).

Could you explain more clearly how the part about の間 is related? I think that's just saying that, if you want to use a noun with 間, you'd connect it with の (i.e. 夏休みの間, "during summer vacation"). But that doesn't really seem related to me to the rest of the question... sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

This doesn't really answer your question, but A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar says that いる can be used directly (e.g. アメリカにいる間) because it is a stative verb. Maybe a native speaker can comment on if that generalizes to other stative verbs as well?

Hello, @JoshGrosso I will check your reference. Yes, I know that いる alone (also because いている would be nonsense) can be used and probably it was a better example. I probably phrased it badly, but I wasn't talking about nouns only in the last part, rather about noun+copula. In other words I was saying that my books seems to suggest that if you want to combine 「noun だ」 with 間 it just becomes 「noun の間」. So my focus was not on what happens but on the fact that the book implicitly suggests you can use 間 with a copula, which is a plain verb.

Please let me know if my explanation is too convoluted and/or suggest possible changes to my question.

Anyways, I think that with いる alone it works because 食べている with a very literal translation would be "eat and exist"(--->be eating), so as long as you "feed" 間 with a stative verb, even if it is alone, then it is ok. Probably the same holds for the copula.

Oh, I see. It's worth noting that だ isn't really a normal verb and often behaves strangely (such as how you have to change it to な or の when using it as a relative clause). I think that's why the book gave it a special mention.

Yes, 田中さんが食べる間 and 田中さんが食べている間 are both correct and they are almost interchangeable. I feel the former is less common and slightly more literary, but that's the only difference I can perceive.
However, pure punctual (also known as instantaneous state-change) verbs must always be in the teiru form, and pure stative verbs such as ある/いる must always be in the plain form:

結婚している間: while you're married
(結婚する間 is incorrect)
覚えている間: as long as you remember it
(覚える間 is incorrect)
痛みがある間: while you have a pain
(痛みがあっている間 is incorrect)

Additionally, I strongly feel 生きる間 is unnatural, and you must say 生きている間 instead to mean "while one is alive". I'm not certain why.

EDIT: Upon further reflection, I feel plain-form + 間 tends to be used before starting the action in question. In other words, this dictionary form might contain a sense similar to the future tense:

私が寝ている間に誰か来たら起こしてください。
(→ 寝る間に is also acceptable)
私が寝ている間に誰か来ましたか？
(→ 寝る間に sounds totally wrong in this case)

This may also explain why 生きる間 sounded unconditionally strange to me. It's impossible to say something from a perspective before being born.
Anyway, ている間 is much more common and safer.

Your answer already addresses my question but I would be very grateful if you gave me your 2 cents regarding why most books will directly introduce this construct with ~ている and possibly use other constructs such as うちに for stative verbs.

@Mr.Feynman Please see the edit. する間 likely has certain constraints that I haven't fully grasped yet... している間 is much more common and safer.

I have read and I think I may understand where you are coming from, nonetheless it's probably a nuance out of  a beginner's reach. Moreover, if such a nuance troubles a native speaker (I would assume you are),  like yourself, then I will treasure this answer and check it later during my studies.

Yes, as a native speaker, I know how to say things in Japanese, but it's often very hard to explain why logically.
